# Access generic objects from different files with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

For a Node.js project I have been working on since I was a teenager with a large amount of different files, I have a bunch of objects that are declared and initialised in `index.js`. All of my function calls start here as well.

To make sure other files can access these objects if needed, I have been passing them along as parameters for every main function, which now that I reconsider it, seems very inefficient: These objects are never modified and will be the same each time the functions are called anyway.

Instead of passing these often used objects as parameters each time, could I make it so I can access them on-demand from any of the files in the project? If it makes it clearer, they are mostly references to a database which is why they don't change.

**What I already considered:**

- Global variables. I suppose this would work, but I prefer not to use them and I feel like there should be a much cleaner way to do this that I'm just not seeing.
- Some type of getter: I've used require to make some files with generic functions that can be called from anywhere in the project as long as I require the file with the generic function where I want to call it from, so I tried this in `index.js`: `exports.getClient = function() { return client; };` This didn't work for me, because if I use `require('./index.js')` in any file from where I want to access `client` that'll initialise index.js again, resulting in double listeners and stuff.
- The above, but I place my generic objects in a separate file with a function to initialise them that I can call from `index.js` on startup. Then there is no problem when I require that file, because that wouldn't call the initialisation a second time. If it's possible though, I'd rather keep these objects' initialisation in `index.js`.

*Now that I think about it, I don't know if two files calling require on each other would even cause them to continuously execute each other in the first place - I was only executing a specific file that was requiring (and thus executing) `index.js` during testing instead of everything. I'll test this after sleeping and post an edit, but still post this for now.*

**Example of my code:**

```
// index.js
const client = new Client();
const db = initialiseDb();
const dbDoc1 = db.doc('1');
const dbDoc2 = db.doc('2');
const dbDoc3 = db.doc('3');

client.on('event', (data) => {
    require('./someFile').someMethod(data, client, dbDoc1, dbDoc2, dbDoc3);
}
```

So instead of writing `require('./someFile').someMethod(data, client, dbDoc1, dbDoc2, dbDoc3);`, I'd much rather use `require('./someFile').someMethod(data);` and just get any of the generic objects later in case someMethod() ends up needing them. I hope there's some clean way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, looks like my second solution would work after all. What I was worried about but didn't know the word for was *circular dependencies*. It turns out, Node.js handles those rather well and require only imports a file once, so it doesn't run again if a file is executed by a file it itself already required.

**Tested it like this:**

```
// test1.js
function callTest1() { console.log('test1.js checking in: ' + Date.now()); }
exports.callTest = callTest1;
console.log('test1.js is executing');
const test2 = require('./test2');
test2.callTest();

// test2.js
function callTest2() { console.log('test2.js checking in: ' + Date.now()); }
exports.callTest = callTest2;
console.log('test2.js is executing');
const test1 = require('./test1');
test1.callTest();
```

Result when executing `test1.js`:

```
test1.js is executing
test2.js is executing
test1.js checking in: 1643405381177
test2.js checking in: 1643405381178
```

What happens is the following:

1. `test1.js` defines `callTest1()` and adds it to its `module.exports`
2. `test1.js` logs `test1.js is executing`
3. `test1.js` requires `test2.js`, which is now executed
4. `test2.js` defines `callTest2()` and adds it to its `module.exports`
5. `test2.js` logs `test2.js is executing`
6. `test2.js` requires `test1.js`, but it was already executed, so this doesn't happen again
7. `test2.js` calls `test1.callTest()`, which logs `test1.js checking in: 1643405381177`
8. `test1.js` finishes executing `test2.js`
9. `test1.js` calls `test2.callTest()`, which logs `test2.js checking in: 1643405381178`

So, looks like I can just place my 'getters' in my `index.js` file. I'll just have to be mindful of the order in which files are loaded, so I don't require `index.js` before its getters are added to `module.exports`. I'll leave this question unanswered for now, in case someone does show up with a cleaner solution.